# can i control the speed of ros running?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I control the speed of ros running on my PC? I have ros hydro installed on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. For some reason, I wish to change the speed of ros running on my system (say i wish to speed up or speed down the code-running at the back end of my ros package, i.e; controlling the ros running speed). Is that possible?

A solution without modification of package code is highly desirable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199975/can-i-control-the-speed-of-ros-running?/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What speed exactly do your what to reduce?

If you want to reduce the rate at which a message callback is being called, you can use topic_tools throttle:

http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle

If you want to adjust an internal loop you can embed a `ros::Rate`, call `.sleep()` on it like in the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Publisher_Node) and use a ros parameter to set the loop rate in your node from the param server without having to change your code....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2